# Android bluetooth exception

Tags: android, bluetooth

Ok, I will try one more time.

I have a device sdptool in ubuntu the following is stated from my device:

```
# sdptool browse  C0:1B:DC:1F:E2:F1
Browsing C0:1B:DC:1F:E2:F1 ...
Service Name: OBEX Object Push
Service RecHandle: 0x10000
Service Class ID List:
 "OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
Protocol Descriptor List:
 "L2CAP" (0x0100)   
 "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
 Channel: 9 
 "OBEX" (0x0008)
Profile Descriptor List:
 "OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
  Version: 0x0100
```

As you can se the device does support the RFCOMM protocol, and OBEX for file transfer. I have a simple code for my android app which tries to connect to this device over a insecure RFCOMM channel, just for no user interaction. I want to connect to this device, so Iam using the device mac-address for connection, and the socket is ready, logcat says so.

But I only get the error:

```
Connection refused
```

Have in mind that the mac-address in the java code is different from the following listed above.

So here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleConnectAndroidActivity extends Activity {

final static String toast = "IAM HERE"; 

final static String TAG ="SimpleConnect";
UUID MY_UUID;

BluetoothDevice bd;
BluetoothAdapter ba;

Button connectButton;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //MY_UUID = new UUID(0x0100 , 0x1000);
    // MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("8e1f0cf7-508f-4875-b62c-fbb67fd34812");

    connectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            BluetoothSocket tmp = null; 

                BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice("00:1B:DC:0F:EC:7E");
                Method m = null;

                try {
                    m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    tmp.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        tmp.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Socket closed!" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 


                }
                boolean con = tmp.isConnected();

                if(con)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection was made!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection was not made!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
    });  
}
```

}

I've read several places that it should work by un-pairing and pair again, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question is over a month old, but in case you're still looking for the answer, here's one:

sdptool indicates that your RFCOMM channel is 9, but in your code you have:

`tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);`

Instead of 1 as your last argument, try 9 (if that doesn't work, try other integers, like 2 through 15).

You may also want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395386/android-bluetooth-bluetoothsocket-cannot-connect).

There seem to be many variations of this question on Stack, but not a lot of understanding of the "standard" recommended code (i.e., the bluetooth chat sample modified with the lines that define and invoke "Method m")--I know because I'm one of those people who struggled with this.  I was trying to connect my phone to my MacBook, and got the "connection refused" message until I realized that I needed to use 5 in the line of code above.